# C char array and \0

Tags: c, c-strings, buffer-overflow

In C, if I initialize a char array like this:

```
char lines[5];
memcpy((char *)line,"Hello",5)
```

Then if I execute the following expression:

```
line[6]='\0';
```

Would this cause buffer overflow? Thanks?

Comment: Of course it will. Everything after `line[4]` is outside the array.

Comment: Why do you write `(char *)line`? That's already its type.

Comment: And why `line[6]` instead of `line[5]`?

Comment: This is the very definition and a canonical example of "buffer overflow". Wat makes you think it is not?

Comment: Even `lines[5]='\0'` would be an overflow.  When you said `char lines[5]`, that got you `lines[0]` through `lines[4]`.

Comment: Should `lines[5]` be `line[5]`?

Comment: Array indexes (indices?) in C are 0-based.  Your declaration `char lines[5];` declares a 5-character array.  Valid index values for that array will be 0 to 4.  After loading it with 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', and 'o' there is no room left to write a '\0'.

Comment: As you probably know, the right thing to do here, if you want a proper, null-terminated string, would be to declare `char line[6]` and then `memcpy(line, "Hello", 6)`.

Comment: Yes, accessing `line[6]` for reading or for writing will cause *undefined behavior*. Since you declared `line` array to have five elements, valid indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. The last index you can safely assign is `4`.

Comment: Would the complier assign 8 bytes for 'lines'? Since 8 is a multiple of 4(the possible word length).

Comment: @XINLIU No. Nothing like that. If you ask for 5, you get 5.

Comment: "Padding" of variable space is an implementation-specific issue, and not required at all. In the past, there was no such thing (you ask 5 bytes, you get 5 bytes, and the next variable allocated is at the very next byte). In the future, padding may go up to 16 or 32 or 4,096 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems. For one, why cast to `char *`, when that is to what the array decays? Second, you need to use a zero-based index, not a one-based index; The first element of array `a` is `a[0]` not `a[1]`.

Also you should have set the buffer size to 6, not 5, to make room for terminator

Comment: The way how the OP explain through its Question it is more over “2 based index” :)))

Answer (score 0):

> Then if I execute the following expression:
>
> ```
> line[6]='\0';
> ```
>
> Would this cause buffer overflow?

Yes. Because `lines` contains five characters and you are overwriting the seventh one.

> Would the comp[il]er assign 8 bytes for 'lines'?

No.

It might put 3 bytes of padding after `lines`, in which case it's still a buffer overflow because `lines` is still 5 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely writing outside the bounds of the array, which leads to *undefined behavior*.  The result could be any of the following:

- a runtime error (segfault);
- corrupted data (overwriting part of another object);
- behaving exactly as expected

Most platforms have alignment requirements such that there may be some unused bytes between the end of the array and the next object in memory<sup>1</sup>, and writing one or two bytes past the end of the array isn't much of an issue.  But that's not the same thing as the compiler allocating "extra space" for the array.

---

1. Assuming the array size isn't a multiple of 2 or 4 bytes, anyway.

Comment: Compile-time error is a possible outcome too ;) `error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]`